# IBM Rational Business Developer for EGL programs, issue with generation output directory

Tags: ibm-rational

My organization uses IBM Rational Business Developer (RBD) to write EGL program for an IBM mainframe system.  The Network folder where out output generation directory is located for the program generations has been moved.  The issue is where within RBD or external to the product do you specify the folder where the output generation directory is located.  We are unable to locate this and it should be easy to change once we know where it is located.  Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 0):

It is specified in the build options inside the build descriptor file(*.eglbld). The option name is something like genProject or genLocation